# Word reminder Application

Tags: windows, language, reminders

Recently I started to learn German, I used to watch TV with subtitles and read some stories.

Actually I use Linguee to translate the words and then write them in a piece of a paper to memorize the new vocabulary, which I find not very efficient.

I am wondering if there is a kind of application that remind you each time of the words recently seen (Kind of a popup on screen).

Linguee Application on the phone contains such a feature but I find that the frequency of these notifcations is too low and it s not possible to configure it.

So If it's possible to configure Linguee to give more notification please help me to know.

Otherwise could you suggest other application ?

Comment: What OS should it run on – and what is your price limit when it comes to paid solutions?

Comment: I am looking for free applications running on Windows

Comment: That leaves us with the price question then :) Mind to fill that gap as well?